# How to change navigation property return type

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, ef-model-first

I read the following article about EF5 [Databinding with WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076).

I use VS2010, .NET 4.0 and EF5 Model First approach, and I don't know how to change navigation property return type in VS2010 EF Designer, without changing auto-generated entity class. For example I need to change navigation property return type from `ICollection<T>` to `ObservableCollection<T>`, but in Properties View there is 'Return type' option disabled.

Comment: Please, please don't use Question Title as a Tag Bar, use the Tag Bar for this purpose instead. And don't use a signature - it's not necessary on SO as far as user pic and his stats are shown. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It is possible to change type of all navigation properties which are collections. Text Template *.tt file for Model First auto-generated entities should be edited.

By default, EF5 generates navigation properties of `HashSet` type:

```
If(edmProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity = RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
     defaultValue = " = New HashSet(Of " & propertyType & ")"
     propertyType = "ICollection(Of " & propertyType & ")"
End If
```

To change navigation properties type to `ObservableCollection<T>`, two lines of *.tt code should be modified:

```
If(edmProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity = RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
     defaultValue = " = New ObservableCollection(Of " & propertyType & ")"
     propertyType = "ObservableCollection(Of " & propertyType & ")"
End If
```

Afterwards, entity classes should be regenerated automatically.